# JSONB PostgreSQL type: how to lookup

Tags: django, jsonb, postgresql-9.4

I am not sure to understand how far we could use the JSONB type of PostgreSQL 9.4

For example, if I store the following in a JSON field:

```
 id |                 data                 
----+--------------------------------------
  1 | {"a": ["1", "2"]}
  2 | {"b": ["1", "5"]}
  3 | {"a": ["1", "3", "8"], "c": ["1", "2"]}
  4 | {"a": ["7", "8"]}
```

How can I select the rows where the JSONB field has a key "a" that has the value "1" in its list?

For this example, the result would be:

```
 id |                 data                 
----+--------------------------------------
  1 | {"a": ["1", "2"]}
  3 | {"a": ["1", "3", "8"], "c": ["1", "2"]}
(2 rows)
```

If yes, how to use it with django?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to write custom lookups and transforms using Django 1.7 or later. You'll need to write a couple of classes which generate the needed SQL.

Another option is to wait for this feature to land in Django. There is a kickstarter project for this, see https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/mjtamlyn/improved-postgresql-support-in-django

Comment: Ok for Django but without talking about Django, is there a way to query what I am looking for in pure SQL? Looking at the http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html, I am not sure it is easily doable to look for a specific value having a dictionary of list.

Comment: Yes there is, use the containment operator, that is WHERE data @> {"a": ["1"]}. Writing this as Django lookup should be easy, data__contains={"a":["1"]}, where contains is a custom lookup producing the @> SQL.

Answer (score 0):

A query that solve your problem is:

```
select *
from mytable
where data -> 'a' ? '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using following query:

```
yourModel.objects.filter(data__contains={"a": [*]})
```

You can have look at [this](http://www.lexev.org/en/2015/trying-json-combo-django-and-postgresql/)